# BigQuery with Airflow - missing projectId

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Trying out the example below:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/how-to-aggregate-data-for-bigquery-using-apache-airflow

While running one of the commands:

```
airflow test bigquery_github_trends_v1 bq_check_githubarchive_day 2017-06-02
```

getting an error : **TypeError: Missing required parameter "projectId"**

**Error stack:**

```
[2017-09-11 16:32:26,630] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: bigquery_github_trends_v1.bq_check_githubarchive_day 2017-06-02 00:00:00 [None]>
[2017-09-11 16:32:26,631] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: bigquery_github_trends_v1.bq_check_githubarchive_day 2017-06-02 00:00:00 [None]>
[2017-09-11 16:32:26,632] {models.py:1318} INFO - 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
---------
Starting attempt 1 of 6
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
---------

[2017-09-11 16:32:26,632] {models.py:1342} INFO - Executing <Task(BigQueryCheckOperator): bq_check_githubarchive_day> on 2017-06-02 00:00:00
[2017-09-11 16:32:26,643] {check_operator.py:75} INFO - Executing SQL check: 
#legacySql
SELECT table_id 
FROM [githubarchive:day.__TABLES__] 
WHERE table_id = "20170601"

[2017-09-11 16:32:26,646] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:73} INFO - Getting connection using `gcloud auth` user, since no key file is defined for hook.
[2017-09-11 16:32:26,671] {models.py:1417} ERROR - Missing required parameter "projectId"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/check_operator.py", line 76, in execute
records = self.get_db_hook().get_first(self.sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 135, in get_first
cur.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 752, in execute
self.job_id = self.run_query(bql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 244, in run_query
return self.run_with_configuration(configuration)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 498, in run_with_configuration
.insert(projectId=self.project_id, body=job_data) \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 716, in method
raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "projectId"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the code for bigquery_hook, you will find it is checking project_id, https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L54

The default connection is bigquery_default unless you override it, go to Airflow UI, go to admin --> connection --> bigquery_default (or whatever you created) --> add project id there

[image]

Comment: This is very useful, any idea how to set it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but I was struggling too since for me the UI didn't work.
Just found out how to do this via CLI and wanted to share my findings since it isn't documented.

There is actually three ways:

1. Via environment variable, as stated [here](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/manage-connections.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables)

```sh
export AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT=google-cloud-platform://:@:?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=yourprojectid&extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=/path/to/keyfile.json
```

2. Via cli and URI

```sh
airflow connections -d --conn_id bigquery_default
airflow connections -a --conn_id bigquery_default --conn_uri 'google-cloud-platform://:@:?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=yourprojectid&extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=/path/to/keyfile.json'
```

3. Via cli and params

```sh
airflow connections -d --conn_id bigquery_default
airflow connections -a --conn_id bigquery_default --conn_type google-cloud-platform --conn_extra '{"extra__google_cloud_platform__project":"yourprojectid", "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path":"/path/to/keyfile.json"}'
```

If you leave out the key path stuff, airflow will use whichever credentials are currently used by gcloud command line tool. Usually your personal user.

Once this is done, you can run any tasks using that connection with `airflow run ...` or `airflow test ...`

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me (I did solution 2). Changing it in the UI seemed to have no effect.