# Airflow conn_id missing

Tags: python, azure, airflow, azure-blob-storage

I'm running a containerized airflow project which loads API data to Azure Blob or Data Lake. I'm currently having trouble getting airflow to identify my connections. I've tried several methods to resolve to issue but I still haven't progressed in fixing this problem.

I've tried manually adding connections in the airflow UI inputting

```
conn_id="azure_data_lake",
conn_type="Azure Blob Storage",
host="",
login= StorageAccountName,    
password=StorageAccountKey
port=""
```

however, once I run the dag I get this error. I've tried running airflow db reset and airflow db init.

```
  File "/opt/airflow/plugins/operators/coinmarketcap_toAzureDataLake.py", line 60, in upload_to_azureLake
    wasb_hook = WasbHook(self.azure_conn_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/wasb.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.connection = self.get_conn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/wasb.py", line 71, in get_conn
    return BlockBlobService(account_name=conn.login, account_key=conn.password, **service_options)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 365, in __get__
    retval = self.descriptor.__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 213, in get_password
    return fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._password, 'utf-8')).decode()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 194, in decrypt
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

If I programmatically add this via a python script. Running the airflow dag gives me a missing conn_id error. But surprisingly when I run the airflow connections list command I see the conn_id in the db.

```
from airflow import settings
from airflow.models import Connection
conn = Connection(
        conn_id="azure_data_lake",
        conn_type="Azure Blob Storage",
        host="", 
        login= StorageAccountName,    
        password=StorageAccountKey
        port=""
) #create a connection object
session = settings.Session() # get the session
session.add(conn)
session.commit()
```

Comment: [Reference1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html), [Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166015/bigquery-with-airflow-missing-projectid).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is a problem with token `cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken`.
The Airflow uses Fernet for all passwords for its connections in the backend database.

The Airflow backend is using the previous fernet key and you have generated a key using which you have created a new connection.

My recommendation is to do the following first:

```
airflow resetdb
```

this will help in deleting all the existing records in your backend db.

Then,

```
airflow initdb
```

this will initialize the backend like fresh.

If the error still persists, change your fernet_key (airflow.cfg > fernet_key)

```
$ python
>>> from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
>>> k=Fernet.generate_key()
>>> print(k)
Z6BkzaWcF7r5cC-VMAumjpBpudSyjGskQ0ObquGJhG0=
```

than, edit $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg